# Getting error when trying to perform Delete operation in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, crud, http-delete

I am receiving the following error when I am trying to perform a delete operation in angular CRUD operations: "ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(29,37): error TS2322: Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'. Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.". Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  products: any[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  id: number;
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  //Url to fetch data: http://localhost:3000/products
  getData(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/products")
      .subscribe(response=>{
        this.products = response as any[];
      });
  }

  deleteProduct(id){
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
      const url = `${"http://localhost:3000/products"}/${id}`;
      return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise()
        .then(()=>{
          this.getData();
        })
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: The class used for headers is called `HttpHeaders` (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders). Exampe: https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated into the error message, the expect type is HttpHeaders, not Headers :

```js
private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```